# How to get the logs using string matching (ex: logs containing "DEBUG")

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

In the elasticsearch cluster we get logs indexed from our cluster. Logstach didnt set any filter so we get all the logs with INFO, DEBUG etc levels. I want to know the query to get just the logs with one specific level.

If it's in python we could do it like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"node.id": [123, 124, 125], 
               "log":["INFO: run", "DEBUG: fail", "WARN: warn"]})

       log        node.id
0    INFO: run      123
1  DEBUG: fail      124
2   WARN: warn      125

df[df["log"].str.contains("DEBUG")]

           log  node.id
1  DEBUG: fail      124
```

I tried using "regex", "wildcard" but doesn't seem to get the right syntax.

Comment: Wildcard should work easily. Can you show us the exact query you are executing? Also, if you are using the default `text` type, you probably have to lower case your input because of the analyzer. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-term-query.html#query-dsl-term-query

Comment: can you show your logstash config ?

Comment: "exists": {
    "field": "log"
  },
  "query": {
  "wildcard": "*info"
  }
}

I'm trying to use query like this. I dont know the config. I am just end user of elk stack after someone configured.